# How get normal SQL query from cake query array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I have array like this

```
$conditions = array("Post.title" => "This is a post");
```

And using **$conditions** array in this method.

```
$this->Post->find('first', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

I want convert the $conditions array to normal sql query.
     I want use

```
$this->Post->query($converted_query);
```

instead of

```
$this->Post->find('first', array('conditions' => $conditions));
```

Comment: Just because? Or do you have a goal you're not describing?

Comment: I have 10 cakephp query. in certain condition ,i want combine this query and execute the combined query in mysqli

Answer (score 1):

```
 $null=null;
 echo  $this->getDataSource()->generateAssociationQuery($this, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, $query_array, false,$null);
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you could do two things:

1) Combine your `$conditions`  arrays and let CakePHP build your new query so you can simply use `$this->Model->find()` again.

2) Use [this](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/grant_cox/2008/06/23/get-the-find-query-sql-rather-than-query-result). It's an expansion for the mysql datasource that adds the option to do `$this->Model->find('sql', array('conditions' => $conditions))` which will return the SQL-query. This option *might* cause trouble, because for some find calls (especially when you're fetching associated models) CakePHP uses multiple queryies to fetch the associated models (especially in case of hasMany-associations).

If at all possible, option 1 will probably cause the least trouble. Another problem with going with 2 is that if you're trying to combine two queries with conflicting conditions (like 'name = Hansel' in query 1 and 'name = Gretel' in query 2) you will just find nothing unless you plan on writing extra code to parse the resulting queries and look for conflicts..
Going with 1 will probably be a lot simpler and will probably avoid lots of problems.